# How to fully communicate with leads in salesforce - and keep it in salesforce

Tags: leads

Our web-to-lead is working flawlessly.

We have an automated template sent to a new user from the system upon assignment.

However, when the assigned owner get's a reply from the lead, he gets it into his personal email.

What are my options to keep this entire communication within salesforce? I want all conversation to be visible within the lead tab in salesforce.

That includes the next email sent from the lead's owner to the lead itself.

We use Gmail, but I am positive I am not the first to want/need this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an InboundEmailHandler and to have the leads respond to a corresponding Salesforce-generated email address.

See [Using the InboundEmail Object - Example 2: Handle Unsubscribe Email](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_inbound_email.htm&language=en_US). It shows looking up leads to update them based on the contents of the email.

You could create something similar that saves the inbound emails as Tasks under the appropriate lead.

In terms of sending emails. Either use the Activity History > Send an Email button on the lead or set your return address to the Salesforce-generated email address in gmail.

[image: Sending outbound emails from a Lead]

---

If you want to stay with gmail, see [Using Gmail in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=google_gmail_activate.htm&language=en_US). This is still going to integrate back to Salesforce Tasks.

Comment: Any solution that is other than using tasks

Comment: I suggested Tasks("Activity History") at that is where Salesforce places sent emails and supports email templates. I guess you could use a custom object to handle the out and inbound emails.